# Sort priority in SQL results

Tags: php, mysql

Below is part of a library that generates lists of models.... the `->getBy()` portion merely takes the SQL and puts it after a `WHERE` clause in SQL.  So it'd execute as: `WHERE site_id = ? ORDER BY name ASC`

```
/**
 * Get areas
 */
public function getAreas() {
    return $this->modelFactory('area')->getBy('site_id = ? ORDER BY name ASC', array($this->siteId));
}

/**
 * Get nested areas
 */
public function getNestedAreas() {
    $nestedAreas = array();
    $areas = $this->getAreas();
    if (is_array($areas)) {
        foreach ($areas as $area) {
            //parent areas
            if ($area->getParentId() == NULL) {
                $nestedAreas[$area->getId()]['area'] = $area;
            } else {
                $nestedAreas[$area->getParentId()]['subareas'][] = $area;
            }
        }
        $areas = $nestedAreas;
    } else {
        $areas = array();
    }
    return $areas;
}
```

The end result is an array like:

array(
   array(
      'area' => new areaModel() //areaModel for Kentucky
      'subareas' => array(
           new areaModel(), //areaModel for Cincinatti
           new areaModel(), //areaModel for Louisville
           new areaModel() //areaModel for Lexington
      )
   )
)

The problem with this setup is that the original `ORDER BY` will put Ohio at the top of my nested areas because it's sub area `Akron / Canton` shows up first by the `ORDER BY`.  Like this:

```
            <select name='area_id'>
                <optgroup label='Ohio'>
                     <option value='905'>Akron / Canton</option>
                     <option value='1154'>Cincinnati</option>
                     <option value='1155'>Cleveland Eastside</option>
                     <option value='908'>Cleveland Westside</option>
                     <option value='910'>Dayton</option>
                     <option value='1394'>Toledo</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label='Alabama'>
                     <option value='988'>Birmingham, AL</option>
                     <option value='1224'>Huntsville</option>
                     <option value='712'>Mobile / Baldwin County</option>
                ....
```

Is it possible to simply adjust my query to properly order the results by those with `parent_id IS NULL` before those that have an integer value for `parent_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like MSSQL's `isnull`, MySQL has `ifnull`.

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(parent_id, 0)
```

will place `null` parent_id's before those with an actual value.